# Pandas csv reader creates NaN index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file with content like this:

```
A: 12, B: 14
A:  1, B:  4
A:  2, B:  1
A: 21, B: 41
```

I can separate the columns with regex:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", sep = ":\s*|,\s*", names = ["dummy1", "A", "dummy2", "B"], engine = "python")
print(df)
```

Output

```
  dummy1   A dummy2   B
0      A  12      B  14
1      A   1      B   4
2      A   2      B   1
3      A  21      B  41
```

To prevent the creation of useless columns, I tried the following strategy:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("test.csv", sep = "A:\s*|,\s*B:\s*", names = ["A", "B"], engine = "python")
print(df1)
```

But now the index contains only `NaN` values:

```
      A   B
NaN  12  14
NaN   1   4
NaN   2   1
NaN  21  41
```

Why does this happen and how can it be prevented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seemingly, this is the expected behaviour of a separator. It is identical for regex/non-regex separators and for the python/c engine as we can see from the following example:

```
A 12 13 A 14 A
A 22 23 A 24 A
A 32 33 A 34 A
```

The script

```
df2 = pd.read_csv("test1.csv", sep = "A", index_col = False, header = None, engine = "c")
print(df2)
```

produces a column of `NaN` values at the beginning and the end:

```
    0        1   2   3
0 NaN   12 13   14 NaN
1 NaN   22 23   24 NaN
2 NaN   32 33   34 NaN
```

This is somewhat surprising, I would have expected the engine to ignore non-existing values. Well, we are all slaves of the code now.
The easiest way out seems to be to facilitate the `csv reader` parameter `usecols` in the first example:

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", sep = ":\s*|,\s*", names = ["A", "B"], usecols = [1, 3],  engine = "python")
print(df)

    A   B
0  12  14
1   1   4
2   2   1
3  21  41
```

This makes the script less flexible, because you have to know the data structure in advance. Suggestions are still welcome.

Answer (score 1):

[`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) function accepts an `index_col` argument which indicates the row labels of the DataFrame (indices). You need to set the this argument with an `int` or sequence of indices because by default it's None.

> `index_col` : int or sequence or False, default None
>
> Column to use as the row labels of the DataFrame. If a sequence is given, a MultiIndex is used. If you have a malformed file with delimiters at the end of each line, you might consider `index_col=False` to force pandas to *not* use the first column as the index (row names)

If still this doesn't work you can drop using `delimiter` and just use a converter function for both columns to separate the number from the alphabetical character:

```
func = lambda x: x.split(':')[-1]
df1 = pd.read_csv("test.csv",
                  names = ["A", "B"],
                  engine = "python",
                  converters={'A': func,
                              'B': func})
```

Output:

```
     A    B
0   12   14
1    1    4
2    2    1
3   21   41
```

Comment: `index_col = False` has a funny effect. Now the index is as expected, but `A` contains `NaN` values and `B` the values of `A`. It is, as if my second version creates an additional column zero containing only `NaN` values. Though I don't see why this should happen.

Comment: @Mr.T Sounds like it's because of omitting those column names or your separator.

Comment: Is it maybe because a separator during the csv import always splits a line into two parts, but because the line starts with the first separator, it creates a NaN value column instead of simply ignoring it? So basically, my strategy is dumb to start with a separator?

Comment: @Mr.T Yes that's definitely possible but separators don't necessarily split into two parts. As it's mentioned in comments when the length of separator is more than one Pandas will treat to them as regex. I think in this case can can only use a whitespace as separator.

Comment: But this is my strategy one that creates more columns than needed. I probably will fall back to `usecols = [1, 3]`, if the second strategy also creates unwanted columns like the first strategy.

Comment: @Mr.T Yes it won't work as expected in this case. Another way around this is to just read the whole `csv` without using delimiter and parse the items manually. Check out the update.